# How to pass a tuple as an argument to `divmod()` function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying this, but failed a lot of times :

```
>>> x = (21, 4)
>>> divmod(x)
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: divmod expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

How can this be possible?

As far as I know, `divmod()` returns a tuple, but why can't it take in a tuple as an argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`divmod()` function returns a tuple and it takes in **multiple** arguments.

To provide a tuple as an argument for `divmod()` function you have to use * **scatters** right before the tuple.

So, your code should be something like :

```
>>> x = (21, 4)
>>> divmod(*x)
(5, 1)
```

So the quotient is `5` and the remainder is `1`